# Modeling many-to-many relationships without an ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Let's say I have a simple database example, something like

```
create table Items
(ItemId int
,ItemName varchar(50)
,ItemCost decimal
,ItemOrigin varchar(50) --maps to reference of country codes
,primary key (ItemId)
)
go
create table Visits
(VisitId int
,VisitDate datetime
,VisitLocation varchar(50) --maps to references of country codes
,primary key (VisitId)
)
go
create table ItemsVisits
(ItemId int
,VisitId int
,ItemsPurchased int
,ItemExpirationDate datetime
,TotalCost decimal --equals price * items purchased
,primary key(ItemId,VisitId)
)



public class Items
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemCost { get; set; }
        public string ItemOrigin { get; set; }
    }
    public class Visits
    {
        public int VisitId { get; set; }
        public DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
        public string VisitLocation { get; set; }
        public List<Items> ItemsPurchased { get; set; }
    }
```

The two simple classes above were my first inclination.  In this example the `Items` table is sort of a reference table to what can be purchased, and the 'meat' of the application is in the `Visits` table.  With the current setup above, I have no way of knowing about the expiration dates of the items purchased. (Pretend in this scenario that a certain ItemId varies with its expiration date depending on the date on which is was purchased).  Should I add a class like

```
 public class ItemsVisits
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int VisitId { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPurchased { get; set; }
        public DateTime ItemExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

    }
```

and then make the `Visits` table have a list of `ItemsVisits` objects as a property?  Or more generally, I suppose, is this a correct way to model a many-to-many relationships when the junction table consists of more than just a copy of the primary keys of both tables? I'll be learning the Entity Framework eventually, but I'd like to be a little closer to the metal while learning.

Comment: I know opinions differ on this practice, but I always put a surrogate key in my many-to-many tables; in this case it would be a `ItemsVisitsId` column. It makes it easier to use the IN clause to maintain the data later. For example, `SELECT... FROM ItemsVisits WHERE ItemsVisitsId IN (list of IDs or a subselect)`

Comment: So you're of the mindset that you don't need to use composite primary keys then?  I'll admit, adhering strictly to relational design kind of sucks when you have to write a bunch of joins and/or join on multiple keys.

Comment: I personally don't use composite keys. I still add the appropriate indexes to make sure the data stays unique by what would have been the composite key. The single column surrogate key makes it easier to maintain later. If you end up needing to delete a bunch of records with some complicated query, you can test it as a select query, and then flip it to a delete query really quickly.

Comment: This is of course a contrived example, but I waffle between doing exactly what you're describing and doing it the good old fashioned way. Personally, I think in the long run I'll prefer using surrogate keys because like you said, it's just easier :).  I would imagine your indexes are narrower as well, and it might perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, building the `ItemVisits` class and then providing the one-to-many relationship via a collection is the right approach. One additional item of interest is you'll need a way to get back to `Visits` and `Items` from `ItemVisits` when you query it. That of course is a more concrete way of saying you need an abstract way of getting from entity-to-entity.

One approach might be lazy-loading. So consider a couple new properties on the `ItemVisits` class:

```
private Item _baseItem;
public Item BaseItem
{
    get
    {
        if (_baseItem != null) { return _baseItem; }

        // go get the item here and set the internal property
    }
}
```

The reason you're going to need this is pretty clear. Let's say you're querying `ItemVisits` and you want to include the `Item.ItemName`, well you can't actually do that because you don't have an `Item`.

Another, more old-fashioned approach, would be to pass in the `Item` and `Visit` objects when constructing the list of `ItemVisit`.

Finally, another more scalable approach, would be to leverage caching and an IoC. In this manner you could leverage the constructor of the `ItemVisit` class and inject those values via an IoC. I **would not recommend this** unless you have *significant* transaction load and reason to believe that you would be building these objects at a ridiculous rate. And when I say significant, I'm talking millions of transactions.

**EDIT:** for multiple primary keys:

If I had a table that was only two primary keys:

```
public class LinkTable
{
    // exists in the table
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    private Item _refItem;
    public Item RefItem
    {
        get
        {
            if (_refItem != null) { return _refItem; }

            // go get the item
        }
    }

    // exists in the table
    public int VisitId { get; set; }

    private Visit _refVisit;
    public Visit RefVisit // sample impl as above
}
```

It's really not any different.

Comment: How would your solution, Mr. Solution, be different if the situation was a regular old many-to-many where the table was nothing more than a couple of primary keys?  I don't think I'm going to have to worry about IoC containers for quite some time in my development :) Thanks for the heads up, though.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, please see my edit to address a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Makes sense enough.  Danke.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more than primary keys in such a table leads to data duplication, which can cause problems:

- what happens if you'd have to update ExpirationDate of an Item?
- what happens if you'll modify a Visit (add another Item)?

Could starting point for such topic would be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

EDIT: I'm not saying that it's a bad solution in general, just pointing out additional possible burden, especially without using ORM. Comments from downvoters would be welcome.

Answer (score -1):

many to many relations in oo is different.

Visits have a propperty ItemsVisits
Items also have a propperty ItemsVisits